# Connect to websocket with cloudflare protection on python

Tags: python, cookies, websocket, cloudflare, ws

The essence of the problem is that I used to connect to websocket by sending Origin, User-Agent, Cookies and the connection worked, now the domain owner decided to change it to the domain of the websocket and put cloudflare protection there, after which my connection method does not work . Advise some method, or information on how to connect to a web socket with cloudflare. Help me pls!!

Example of my code:

```
import websocket
import json
import time
import traceback

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36 OPR/68.0.3618.173', 'cookie': '__cfduid=da97b059db0292806e2affdf9c3f4fd8b1593022325; _csrf=i8W6njc7hUXMOf4iQjiAxKg1; language=en; theme=darkTheme; pro_version=false; csgo_ses=1489162147d69debd9fe5d0ea2e445c87a117578d774502172d7151b89b82f7f; steamid=76561199068891508; avatar=https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb_medium.jpg; username=andrewcrook232; thirdparty_token=06d04856ce6e334aa1368696df775e7ba0b1b898db135b0af0b5dc0fe001dd55; user_type=old; sellerid=6721648; type_device=desktop', 'origin': 'https://cs.money'}

def start_ws():
    try:
        ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://ws.cs.money/ws", on_message = on_message, cookie = json.dumps(headers))
        print("Connected")
        while True:
            ws.run_forever(ping_timeout=20)
            print("Reload")
            time.sleep(20)
    except:
        print(traceback.format_exc())

def on_message(ws, message):
    try:
        print(message)
    except:
        print(traceback.format_exc())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_ws()
```

Below is all the information that I got with Chrome Inspector (f12) -> Network -> WS -> headers, this information should be more than enough to successfully join WSS.

```
Request URL: wss://ws.cs.money/ws
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 101 Switching Protocols
alt-svc: h3-27=":443"; ma=86400, h3-28=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
CF-RAY: 5a886ad37f4b8ac6-KBP
cf-request-id: 038921182700008ac6798a2200000001
Connection: upgrade
Date: Wed, 24 Jun 2020 18:12:29 GMT
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: zrH4CEKXm3BY5z77HroJDqGgYSc=
Server: cloudflare
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
Upgrade: websocket
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Upgrade
Host: ws.cs.money
Origin: https://cs.money
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key: GXVT8QewAgPEZDEZZ+x3dA==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Upgrade: websocket
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36 OPR/68.0.3618.173
```

Also additional page data:

```
Request URL: https://cs.money/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 104.20.76.156:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
alt-svc: h3-27=":443"; ma=86400, h3-28=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
cf-ray: 5a886ab5adac8aea-KBP
cf-request-id: 038921058800008aea96109200000001
content-encoding: br
content-security-policy: script-src 'self' cs.money dev.csgo.trade gleam.io www.am4charts.com translate.google.com translate.googleapis.com www.googletagmanager.com www.googleoptimize.com www.google-analytics.com connect.facebook.net https://vk.com 'unsafe-inline' top-fwz1.mail.ru 'unsafe-eval' api.usersnap.com cdn.usersnap.com cs.money mc.yandex.ru diffuser-cdn.app-us1.com diffuser-cdn.app-us1.com prism.app-us1.com trackcmp.net api.basisid.com https://cdn.amplitude.com sc-static.net support.cs.money embed-sandbox.bridgerpay.com embed.bridgerpay.com cs.money; worker-src 'self' data: blob: cs.money; object-src cs.money dota.money; media-src cs.money dota.money; frame-src cs.money dota.money onesignal.com https://*.com https://*.ru https://*.ua http://www.youtube.com
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Wed, 24 Jun 2020 18:12:25 GMT
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
server: cloudflare
set-cookie: user_type=old; Path=/
set-cookie: language=en; Max-Age=8640000; Domain=cs.money; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 02 Oct 2020 18:12:25 GMT
set-cookie: language=en; Max-Age=8640000; Domain=.cs.money; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 02 Oct 2020 18:12:25 GMT
set-cookie: sellerid=6721648; Max-Age=8640000; Domain=cs.money; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 02 Oct 2020 18:12:25 GMT
set-cookie: pro_version=false; Max-Age=8640000; Domain=cs.money; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 02 Oct 2020 18:12:25 GMT
status: 200
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
x-cache-status: BYPASS
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-dns-prefetch-control: off
x-download-options: noopen
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-powered-by: PHP 4.1.0
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
:authority: cs.money
:method: GET
:path: /
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
cache-control: max-age=0
cookie: __cfduid=da97b059db0292806e2affdf9c3f4fd8b1593022325; _csrf=i8W6njc7hUXMOf4iQjiAxKg1; language=en; theme=darkTheme; pro_version=false; csgo_ses=1489162147d69debd9fe5d0ea2e445c87a117578d774502172d7151b89b82f7f; steamid=76561199068891508; avatar=https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb_medium.jpg; username=andrewcrook232; thirdparty_token=06d04856ce6e334aa1368696df775e7ba0b1b898db135b0af0b5dc0fe001dd55; user_type=old; sellerid=6721648; type_device=desktop
referer: https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login?openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fauth.dota.trade%2Flogin%2Fcallback%3FredirectUrl%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fcs.money%26callbackUrl%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fcs.money%2Flogin&openid.realm=https%3A%2F%2Fauth.dota.trade
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
sec-fetch-user: ?1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36 OPR/68.0.3618.173
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the real reason, but it seems that your code has some bug.

If you need to build a websocket connection with customized header, you pass it to `header` parameter, instead of json dump it.

```py
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://ws.cs.money/ws",
    on_message = on_message, 
    cookie = json.dumps(headers))
```

should be

```py
cookie_string = headers['cookie']
del headers['cookie']
header_without_cookie = headers

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://ws.cs.money/ws",
    on_message = on_message,
    header = header_without_cookie,
    cookie = cookie_string)
```

websocket-client documentation is missing, maybe you can read source code about usage

https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client/blob/2222f2c49d71afd74fcda486e3dfd14399e647af/websocket/_app.py